# spark scala can't find codec for java.lang.class

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

Newbie to spark and scala. I'm trying to execute a very simple spark program via intellij-idea. All it is doing is:

1. Connect to a mongodb database to a specific collection
2. Load data
3. print the first record.

It was working fine, but now it is throwing the error:

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find
>   a codec for class java.lang.Class.

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import com.mongodb.spark._
import com.mongodb.spark.rdd.MongoRDD
import org.bson.Document
import com.mongodb.spark.config._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import com.mongodb.spark.sql._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Analytics1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Analytics1").setMaster("local").
      set("spark.mongodb.input.uri","mongodb://192.168.56.1:27017/events.entEvent")
        .set("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://192.168.56.1:27017/events..entResult")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val rdd = sc.loadFromMongoDB()
println(rdd.first())

sc.stop()

  }
}
```

Here is my .sbt. If i use the latest version of spark, then it throws this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame

so I'm using 1.6.1, **which was working fine until a few days ago**, but now it is throwing the

> java.lang.class

error. Someone please help so that I can get moving. Since this is very basic, i'm hopeful that someone will throw some advise and get me unblocked.

Thanks.

```
    name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

// libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"

//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "1.6.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.6.1"

//libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" % "mongo-spark-connector_2.10" % "1.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.1"

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
resolvers += "snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ "
resolvers += "releases"  at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
```

Comment: People looking for answers on this issue, Please read all the comments by Wan below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" % "mongo-spark-connector_2.10" % "1.1.0"

You're loading the [MongoDB Connector for Spark](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/v1.1/) for Scala version 2.10. Although, your project is using Scala version 2.11.7, including the `mongo-scala-driver`.

Swap the line above to:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" % "mongo-spark-connector_2.11" % "1.1.0"
```

Alternatively use the shortcut to use given Scala version by specifying double `%`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "1.1.0"
```

See more about [SBT dependencies: Getting the right Scala version](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTDependencies#Getting-the-right-Scala-version-with-%%)

Comment: Thanks Wan. I tried both the options but no success. I even tried my mllib dependency using the shortcut with %%. That also did not help. My guess is this has something to do with dependencies and /or imports that I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: I think the problem is `println`. If I use `rdd.toDF().show(10)` instead of `println(rdd.first())`. It works. But the data is shown as a DF. But I want it like an RDD output. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: You need to describe the `problem` that you're having with error messages etc. Are you saying now the `codec java.lang.class` is gone but you're getting another error with `println`? Make a smaller script, test and debug. Post any error messages and a small reproducible script.

Comment: When I use `println(rdd.first())` it throws the `java.lang.class` error. If I use `rdd.toDF().show(1)`, it works fine. But the problem with this methid is that it returns the result in dataframe format. I need it in RDD format. Simpler script?, I'm just declaring the config parameters for mongo, spark context and rdd, then printing the first record. What is simpler than this?

Comment: 1) Update your `build.sbt` on your post to reflect the changes you've done. 2) You should only need 3 dependencies for what you're trying to do. `spark-core`, `spark-sql` and `mongo-spark-connector`. Try it in that order. 3) Remove unnecessary imports statements. You should only need `org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}`, `org.mongodb.spark._`, `com.mongodb.spark.config._` and `org.bson.Document`. 4) Do a `sbt clean` or remove previous builds as you still sourced the previous incorrect versions of dependencies. 5) If you're still having problem, post the exact error logs.

Comment: I updated the SBT with the latest one in my post. I will do the rest of the tasks and will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Wan: I have done all the steps you recommended except sbt clean (did not know how to do that in intelliJ :-( ) and IT SEEMS TO BE WORKING!!! Yay!! So far so good. I have other issues but will try to resolve them. But this got me moving. Thanks a lot!!!